# I get error with Logstash: IllegalStateException

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Here is my logstash.conf:

```
input {
   mongodb{
    uri => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/vnExpressCrawler?authSource=vnExpressCrawler'
    placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
    placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
    collection => 'articles'
    batch_size => 5000
  }
 }

filter {
 }

output {
   stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
     }
   elasticsearch { 
    action => "index"
    index => "mongo_log_data"
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```

I get error:
Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for
`PipelineAction::Create<main>`
create at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:135
add at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:60
when I run logstash -f logstash.conf
Can someone help me solve this?

My Log:

```
Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
Sending Logstash logs to C:/Dev Programs/Logstash/logstash-7.13.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-06-21T14:21:04,709][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: C:\Dev Programs\Logstash\logstash-7.13.2\config\log4j2.properties
[2021-06-21T14:21:04,723][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.13.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.16.0 (2.5.7) 2021-03-03 f82228dc32 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.251-b08 on 1.8.0_251-b08 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2021-06-21T14:21:04,867][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2021-06-21T14:21:06,405][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-06-21T14:21:07,828][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 81 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 24 keys and 48 values
[2021-06-21T14:21:08,619][ERROR][logstash.plugins.registry] Unable to load plugin. {:type=>"input", :name=>"mongodb"}
[2021-06-21T14:21:08,635][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (PluginLoadingError) Couldn't find any input plugin named 'mongodb'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the mongodb input plugin resulted in this error: Unable to load the requested plugin named mongodb of type input. The plugin is not installed.", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.<init>(CompiledPipeline.java:119)", "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt.initialize(JavaBasePipelineExt.java:86)", "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.call(JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.gen)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:837)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuper(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1169)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuperSplatArgs(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1156)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InstanceSuperInvokeSite.invoke(InstanceSuperInvokeSite.java:39)", "C_3a_.Dev_20_Programs.Logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_13_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$initialize$0(C:/Dev Programs/Logstash/logstash-7.13.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:332)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:86)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:939)", "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)", "C_3a_.Dev_20_Programs.Logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_13_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0(C:/Dev Programs/Logstash/logstash-7.13.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52)", "C_3a_.Dev_20_Programs.Logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_13_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0$__VARARGS__(C:/Dev Programs/Logstash/logstash-7.13.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)", "C_3a_.Dev_20_Programs.Logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_13_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.RUBY$block$converge_state$2(C:/Dev Programs/Logstash/logstash-7.13.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:389)", "org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.callDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:138)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:52)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:139)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:318)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:105)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"]}
warning: thread "Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>" terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<main>`
          create at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:135
             add at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:60
  converge_state at C:/Dev Programs/Logstash/logstash-7.13.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:402
[2021-06-21T14:21:08,649][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] An exception happened when converging configuration {:exception=>LogStash::Error, :message=>"Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<main>`"}
[2021-06-21T14:21:08,655][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException` for `PipelineAction::Create<main>`>, :backtrace=>["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:135:in `create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:60:in `add'", "C:/Dev Programs/Logstash/logstash-7.13.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:402:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2021-06-21T14:21:08,679][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.16.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.16.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.Dev_20_Programs.Logstash.logstash_minus_7_dot_13_dot_2.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(C:\Dev Programs\Logstash\logstash-7.13.2\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:89) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: Can you post the full error you're getting in the logs?

Comment: ok, I will post All the log

Answer (score 1):

The problem is stated in the error logs

> Couldn't find any input plugin named 'mongodb'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the mongodb input plugin resulted in this error: Unable to load the requested plugin named mongodb of type input. The plugin is not installed.

So you need to make sure to first [properly install](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb) the `mongodb` input plugin before running Logstash.